# regex for dialing in jquery.tablesorter.js numeric field

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm adding a parser to dial in jquery.tablesorter.js:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ etc...
```

but I need to sort some numbers thusly, and I am bordering on useless with regex:

```
40.01.02.31
40.01.02.31.01
40.01.02.32
```

the numbers can have up to 8 "octets", so the minimum would be:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx
```

and the max would be:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx
```

How do I do this? I tried using the very nice regex generator at http://txt2re.com/, but it's not quite doing it..

Can someone chime in and mercilessly correct me?

:)

Thank you!

Comment: thank you for helping, not quite - I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/crunchfactory/L59GU/

Comment: Above, it looks more like I stated minimum 4 octets with a max of 8. "the numbers can have up to 8 "octets""

Comment: And that regex matches a minimum of 4 and max of 8, see [here](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1uU3/2)

Comment: It does now, as the code is slightly different; thank you very much! tablesorter.js is still not sorting them "quite" correctly, but at least I have a running start it now, and again, thank you very much for your perseverance and skill - AND, despite googling like a madman, regex101 should definitely be at the top of the results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d+){3,7}$/
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1uU3/2)